# How can I return a function as a string in Python?

Tags: python, function

I've made a function that will create functions and write them to a file but the problem is they write to the file as the default **repr**. How can I write them to a file as a normal function?

```
def make_route(title):
    test = 1
    def welcome():
        return test + 1

    welcome.__name__ = title 
    with open('test2.py', 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n%s\n' % (welcome))

    return welcome
```

I need it to write

```
def welcome():
    return test + 1
```

to the file

Comment: So where's the code?

Comment: can you put some input and output plz?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html

Comment: Writing functions to a file doesn't make much sense. Can you explain more specifically what you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: Your code write `<function make_route.<locals>.welcome at 0x7fd2c9cf59d8>` into the file, so what do you mean about *default repr* ?

Comment: @KevinGuan Yeah I've added some source code, I just had to simplify my original post, I posted prematurely by accident.

Comment: That edit doesn't help much. Again, what do you actually want to accomplish? Do you want to write the function's source code to a file? Or its bytecode, perhaps?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah sorry, I want to write the source code.

Comment: More possible duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014722/viewing-the-code-of-a-python-function) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562759/can-python-print-a-function-definition). Just Google SO for "python function source code."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks  I just returned a string in the end I was just curious if there was a more elegant way but thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

you need to serialize your function using [marshal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html#module-marshal)

```
import marshal
def f(x): return 2*x
saved = marshal.dumps(f.func_code)
```

then you can use saved string:

```
import marshal, types
code = marshal.loads(saved)
f= types.FunctionType(code, globals(), "your_name")

f(10)  #returns 20
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question, which demonstrates why it's generally better to hold off on answering until the question is more clear.